# Using field in where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Model with two fields: `date1` and `date2`. I'd like to build a query which select data where `date2 + 10 > date1`.

`Model::where('date2', '>', 'date1');`

works but not

`Model::where('date2', '>', 'date1' + 10);`

Comment: Note: That `date1` is a field, but `date1 + 10` is an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the raw method (or Expression class) to tell Eloquent you want the raw expression inserted into the query, not a field or string.

```
Model::where('date2', '>', DB::raw('date1 + 10'));
```